# EF Core PlatformNotSupported on Linux

Tags: linux, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to develop a small web application using [.NET 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) + [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/install). So far I have been able to run the application but when trying to connect to my Azure DB database it fails dramatically throwing a Strings.PlatformNotSupported Exception, as shown in the following stack trace:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Gepro.Seguimiento.Core.Controllers.UsuariosController.Index() in /home/barclow/Documents/Desarrollo/Gepro.Seguimiento.Core/Controllers/UsuariosController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Is EF Core compatible with Linux? - I remember deploying this proof of concept to a linux docker in azure and it worked, but somehow, I can't make it work on my manjaro linux. I understand this shouldn't be an issue related to my installation of linux, since I'm able to run the web app perfectly.

Comment: What if you _don't_ use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` ?

Comment: @Dai Sure, how do I do that? - this is the underlying processes behind EF Core, not exactly my code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue apparently is related to with SDK 6.0.100 version of .netCore, when upgrading to SDK 6.0.101 everything worked properly.

Also, I had AUR package for dotnet, so I had to remove it and then used the official script to upgrade by following [this](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1427#issuecomment-994060176) instructions.

```
curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | sudo bash /dev/stdin -c LTS --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

dotnet --list-sdks
# 6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes
# Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
# Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```